# how to add different entity as a property to object with @OneToOne

Tags: java, jpa

I have two entities in my application: `House` and `Photo`.

`House` has a property `mainPhoto` which has a `@OneToOne` relation to `Photo`

Everything works fine here. Now I want to create a form for an admin where he will be able to add a new `House`. I want to add an upload field where he can select a `Photo`.

How can I get this `Photo`, put it in a table named `photo` (create an object from it with some predefined values + this photo) and set the relationship between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be rather trivial in JPA.

After the upload, instantiate a `Photo` object and assign it to the `mainPhoto` property of `House`. Then just merge the result into the persistent context. Make sure you have merge cascading enabled on the relation.

Basically something along the lines of:

```
Photo photo = new Photo();
// set photo properties according to uploaded file

house.setMainPhoto(photo);
entityManager.merge(house);
```

Comment: yes I think that is the best way to do it. thank you for your tip. I was looking (dunno why) some magic method